# Upgrading Asus Q500A to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, asus-laptop

I have an Asus Q500A with Windows 8.1.  I'd like to upgrade it to Windows 10.  Asus doesn't offer Windows 10 drivers, saying that this laptop is support-only.

I have seen a couple of Q500A's on EBay stating they are Windows 10, so it looks possible.

I have expertise with Windows and experience with Windows 10, so I can handle it if the drivers are there.  Does anyone have any experience with this upgrade?

Speccy Summary:

```
Summary
        Operating System
            Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit
        CPU
            Intel Core i7 3632QM @ 2.20GHz  82 °C
            Ivy Bridge 22nm Technology
        RAM
            8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 789MHz (11-11-11-28)
        Motherboard
            ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Q500A (SOCKET 0)  87 °C
        Graphics
            Generic PnP Monitor (1920x1080@60Hz)
            HP 2509 (1920x1080@59Hz)
            Intel HD Graphics 4000 (ASUStek Computer Inc)
        Storage
            238GB PLEXTOR PX-256M2S (SSD)
            931GB Hitachi HGST HTS721010A9E630 (SATA)   36 °C
        Optical Drives
            No optical disk drives detected
        Audio
            Realtek High Definition Audio
```

Comment: You can get Windows 10 compatible drivers directly from Realtek.  Intel also supplies their own Windows 10 compatible display drivers.  There is nothing about the listed devices that makes your laptop incompatible with Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound  Good deal.  I'll pull them beforehand.  If you want to post as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Windows will download all drivers automatically after the setup is finished.

Comment: Up on Windows 10 now.  Working great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up on Windows 10 now. Working great. Thanks. – R_G Jan 1 at 13:02